# C++ template help, using a template for integrations

Tags: c++, templates

Hi i'm following a tutorial and video i found online , im trying to make a template to preform a numerical integration of a function where a user can decide which form of integration to preform, im trying to keep it to one file as not to use headers and not use massive ammounts of loops , the code for the first integration works fine on its own but when i run it through a template i get the wrong answer and the same value 1.9147e-307 for every input what am i doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

//declared function
double F(double X)
{
   double f;

   f = (X*X);
   return f;
};

double unifRand()
{
    return rand() / double(RAND_MAX);
};

template<typename T> class INTG{
    private:
        T a;
        T b;
        T n;
    public:
        INTG(T a, T b,T n){
            INTG::a = a;
            INTG::b = b;
        }

        ~INTG(){}

        T MC() {
            // some code

            return ans;}

        T SIMPC(){ // Simpson integration code here
            return a+b+n;
        }
};

int main() {
    double a,b,mc,simp,ans;
    int OP,n;
    cout<<"Enter 1 for Monte Carlo Integration , Enter 2 for Composite Simpson Integration, enter 3 for trapezoidal int...."<<endl;
    cin>>OP;
    clock_t start = clock();


    if (OP == 1) {
        cout<<"Enter lower limit of integration"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Enter upper limit of integration"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"Enter number of iterations"<<endl;
        cin>>n;
        ans = INTG<double>::MC(a, b, n);
        INTG<double> MyCalc(a,b,n);

        cout<< ans <<endl;

        //mc =  INTG::MC(a, b, n);
        getch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ans` is never assigned a value. That would account for your 1.9147e-307.

Did you intend

```
ans = MyCalc.MC();
```

before the `cout` ?

Also

```
INTG(T a, T b,T n){
    INTG::a = a;
    INTG::b = b;
}
```

Is better described as

```
INTG(T a, T b, T n):a(a),b(b),n(n) {}
```

Initializing instead of assigning, and remembering n.

So the calculation sequence would be

```
INTG<double> MyCalc(a,b,n);
ans = MyCalc.MC();
```

Comment: +1 ding ding.  I didn't see that until I finished reformatting the code :( my brain's too anal.

Comment: i get an error no match for call'(INTGM<double>) (double&, double&, int&) looking it up now

Answer (score 2):

`if (OP = 1) {`

...should be...

`if (OP == 1) {`

Comment: thanks . fixed the error , i still get the same wrong answer thou